# Comparing 2 names and their ages in prolog

Tags: prolog

Hello I have a huge database on prolog and I am trying to write a rule that compares two names and their age.
For example my data base is:
age(A,12)
age(B,56)
age(C, 80)
...

I would like to write a rule where the user will input name A and Name B (A,B) and the program determines if a is bigger than b.

Comment: What did you try, what is not working with that?

Comment: `age(A,12) age(B,56) age(C, 80)` isn't valid Prolog code. Can you please provide your input as valid Prolog code, and show us the query you're trying to run (i.e. `?- is_older(A, B).`)? Do you know how to accept user input in Prolog? If so, please show us that code too. In short, please get this down to as much code as possible so that we only have to write the final predicate. Otherwise this is too much work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this simple approach:

```
age(bill,12).
age(bob,56).
age(betty,80).

older(NAME_A,NAME_B) :-
    age(NAME_A,AGE_A),
    age(NAME_B,AGE_B),
    AGE_A > AGE_B.

/*

?- older(bill,bob).
false.

?- older(bob,bill).
true.

*/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
age(bill,12) .
age(bob,56) .
age(betty,80) .

older(NAME_A,NAME_B,OLDER)
:-
age(NAME_A,AGE_A) ,
age(NAME_B,AGE_B) ,
older_compare(AGE_A,AGE_B,OLDER)
.

older_compare(AGE_A,AGE_B,true)
:-
AGE_A > AGE_B ,
!
.

older_compare(AGE_A,AGE_B,false)
.

/*

?- older(bill,bob,OLDER) .
OLDER = false .

?- older(bob,bill,OLDER) .
OLDER = true .

?- older(bill,bob,OLDER) .
OLDER = false .

?- older(betty,bob,OLDER) .
OLDER = true .

?- older(bob,betty,OLDER) .
OLDER = false .

?- older(betty,bill,OLDER) .
OLDER = true .

?- older(bill,betty,OLDER) .
OLDER = false .

*/
```

Comment: It's not very Prolog-ish to succeed on failure.

Comment: Hey Thank you for your response. Would it be okay if i could ur email so I could ask u one more question regarding prolog?

Comment: kintalken@gmail.com